# How to refer to existing variable(s) without creating a new one?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, cs3

I have no idea how to ask this question.

I have a variable

```
public static var MaxDurabilityTestItem:Number = 3;
```

I have a function

```
    public static function setItemInSlot(Item:String, Slot:Number, MaxDurability:Number = 0)
    {
        UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryItems[Slot] = Item;

        if(MaxDurability == 0)
        {
            trace("Before change " + UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability);
            UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability[Slot] = "MaxDurability" + Item;
            trace("After change " + UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("not using default durability");
        }
    }
```

The only part of this function that is causing me headaches is this line

```
UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability[Slot] = "MaxDurability" + Item
```

It outputs

> Before change 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> After change 0,MaxDurabilityTestItem,0,0,0,0,0,0

While I want it to output

> Before change 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> After change 0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0

I know the issue, however, I don't know how to fix it.  `"MaxDurability" + Item` makes a string called `MaxDurabilityTestItem`, rather than referring to my variable `MaxDurabilityTestItem`.

How can I change this so that it refers to my variable MaxDurabilityTestItem, rather than this string it creates?

Comment: Static property is a property of class. You can address it via class reference: ClassReference[StaticPropertyName]. If your class name is MyClass, it will be MyClass['MaxDurabilityTestItem'].

Comment: Why `"MaxDurability" + Item`? Is that `Item` likely to change?

Comment: Yes Item will be changing.  This function is to set the durability of the item for the slot the item is in.

Comment: @Organis I realise that my question has been answered, but to expand on the ClassReference[StaticPropertyName] portion, how would it be done for a function?  I tried ItemHandling[Item + "Effect"];  - but (1.) it did not work, and (2.) I do not know where to put the parentheses -- that is if you are at all supposed to at all.  (the function name is TestItemEffect in this case)

Comment: @UnAlpha Ok, I posted some explanations below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `"MaxDurability" + Item` makes a string called `MaxDurabilityTestItem`,

Because you automatically defined a `"string"` by using the quotes. I can only assume `Item` is also string with text `"TestItem"`. So you've simply **joined**+**two**+**strings** together.

(2)

> ...rather than referring to my variable `MaxDurabilityTestItem`.

Try as:

```
UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability[Slot] = MaxDurabilityTestItem; //now using your defined variable
```

**Edit** :

Just in case you **really** want to use a string as reference to the variable itself :

Use `this[ "name of some var" ]`... where `this` will target the current class and `["name"]` will find such specified variable within the current class.

Try:

```
if(MaxDurability == 0)
{
    trace("Before change " + UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability);
    UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability[Slot] = this[ "MaxDurability" + Item ];
    trace("After change " + UI_Taskbar_Inventory.InventoryDurability);
}
else
{ trace("not using default durability"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

**The first thing** I need to say here, is, despite all described below works just fine, that resorting to such techniques **might** indicate some deep problems with the project's architecture. Well, then...

The beauty and ugliness of **ActionScript 3** is that literally anything is an object in it, and you can approach any instance as such.

Any class instance is an object. You can address any **DisplayObject**'s **x** and **y** as ['x'] and ['y'] respectively. You can approach methods in the same way:

```
function gotoAnd(frame:*, thenPlay:Boolean):void
{
    // Forms 'gotoAndPlay' or 'gotoAndStop' string.
    var methodName = 'gotoAnd' + (thenPlay? 'Play': 'Stop');

    // Gets method reference to either gotoAndPlay or to gotoAndStop.
    var methodItself:Function = this[methodName];

    // Calls method by the reference.
    methodItself(frame);

    // In one line:
    // this['gotoAnd' + (thenPlay? 'Play': 'Stop')](frame);
}
```

Any class is an object too. The subtle difference is that the members of a class as an object are static class methods and fields. For example:

```
import flash.system.System;

// Accepts "free" or "private" or "total" as an argument.
function getMemory(value:String = "total"):Number
{
    var propertyName:String;

    switch (value)
    {
        case "private":
            propertyName = "privateMemory";
            break;

        case "free":
            propertyName = "freeMemory";
            break;

        case "total":
            propertyName = "totalMemoryNumber";
            break;

        // Returns -1 for an invalid argument.
        default:
            return -1;
            break;
    }

    // Returns either System.privateMemory
    // or System.freeMemory or System.totalFreeMemory.
    return System[propertyName];
}
```

Then again, static class methods are **Function** members of a class as an object:

```
// Direct method access.
System.gc();

// Property-based method access.
System['gc']();
```

Keep in mind, that [] access still respects the **private**, **internal** and **protected** namespaces, so if you cannot access SomeObject.someMethod() because the method is marked **private**, you won't be able to access it via SomeObject['someMethod'] either. The former will give you a compile-time error, the latter will let you compile  your app then will make you deal with runtime exception.